# Explanation for extra portion of Brachistochrone curve?

Tags: brachistochrone-problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve

In this article, it points out that the curve taking the shortest time from point A to point B under constant acceleration has a different segment from the Tautochrone curve.

How come the minimal time isn't taken from the top of the curve to its vertex? Why is this extra upward-sloping component necessary to minimize travel time past the vertex?

Comment: By allowing the bead to fall farther, it moves faster (that is, more potential energy is converted to kinetic)

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to your question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: The curve comes from making it a solution of Euler-Lagrange equation. If you need a physical explantion then add more details to the question and also maybe look at geometric solutions and such others which are mentioned on the wikipedia as well.

Comment: I think Digiproc answered it, but thank you.